# Laravel Relationship result can not fetch for same foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My table looks like below,

```
donation_requests
---------------------------------------------------------------
| id    name    donation_type_id    donation_request_type_id
|--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     xyz     1                   3
| 2     pqr     3                   2
| 3     abc     3                   1
| 4     klm     4                   1


donation_types
------------------------
| id    name
-----------------------
| 1     jakat
| 2     sadka
| 3     lillah
| 4     fitra


donation_request_types
------------------------
| id    name
-----------------------
| 1     widow
| 2     masjid
| 3     madresha
```

i want donation_request data with donation_types name and donation_request_types name
In my DonationRequest model code is as below

```
public function donation_types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DonationType','id','donation_type_id');
}

public function donation_request_types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DonationRequestType','id','donation_request_type_id');
}
```

but in first two row i get proper result but for third row has same donation_type_id as 3 so it give blank and same as in donation_request_type_id

[image: tinker screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my above question relationship is working fine, and it has issue in laravel tinker. While testing in postman i found perfect result, but in tinker there will be some issue. Update tinker but still have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function donation_types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DonationType');
}

public function donation_request_types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DonationRequestType');
}
```

Comment: i want answer with donation_type and donation_request_type your answer give me blank values

Comment: i think that you have a mistake somewhere in naming. Here is a belongsTo relationship and we can use `magic` of laravel cause when table name and foreign key have same name like ('users', 'user_id' or 'donation_types', 'donation_type_id') we do not have to specifty this in relation

Comment: i know about that, and also i get result for first row and second row see in above screenshot.